# Strong compact elements in lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

I wonder whether there is a name for the following stronger notion of compactness in lattices, namely that if for a respective element $a$ we have that $a \le \bigvee\limits_{i\in I} b_i$ then there exists $j\in I$ such that $a \leq b_j$. Clearly, if the order is total then this is precisely the concept of compact element. But what about in the general case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That will be a [completely join-prime element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Important_lattice-theoretic_notions).
A join-prime element $x$ is one that satisfies
$$x \leq a \vee b \quad\Rightarrow x \leq a \;\text{ or }\; x \leq b.$$
This can be generalized to finitely many elements:
$$x \leq \bigvee_{i=1}^n a_i \quad\Rightarrow\quad x \leq a_i, \;\text{ for some}\; i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}.$$
If for any set $I$,
$$x \leq \bigvee_{i \in I} a_i \quad\Rightarrow\quad x \leq a_i, \;\text{ for some}\; i \in I,$$
then $x$ is said to be completely join-prime.